# component is rendered empty in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to render my own layout with React.

index.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from './Layout';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div id="main">Hello<Layout></Layout></div>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
)
```

Layout.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

function Layout(props) {
    return (
        <h1>world!</h1>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

when I watch that in the browser, then it only renders an emty `div` instead of my `h1`-element:

[image]

However it should render `Hello world!`.

This is my `tsconfig.js`-file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "jsx": "react",
        "watch": true,
        "target": "ES5",
        "lib": ["ES6", "DOM"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

and this my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react_tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "carsten schumann",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-d3-library": "^1.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Also, can you share a code sandbox link for the same?

Comment: @kiner_shah trying out currently... cannot see any errors in the console, just a few performance-issues concerning webpack, which I doubt are relevant here.

Comment: Is the `import` path working correctly?

Comment: Can you try `import React from 'react';` instead? And same for `ReactDOM`?

Comment: @kiner_shah nithing changed with `import React from 'react'`.

Comment: @Shahriar how would I check for that? I don't see any errors in the console. so I assume it does work.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache? Or maybe if you can try passing some dummy props to Layout - Since in the Inspect Element it shows a div, just guessing it's taking some default value which is `div` (this will be weird though).

Comment: @kiner_shah I even restarted my browser. And caching is disabled while DevTools is open.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I tested on code sandbox and it works just fine. Not sure but maybe this config file has something to do with the issue - is this the complete config file?

Comment: @kiner_shah yes, that's the entire tsconfig. I also added packacke.json, just for completeness.

Comment: Try other paths for import: `Layout.tsx`, `/Layout.tsx`, `./Layout.tsx`, `Layout`, `/Layout`...

Comment: @Shahriar all yield to compiler-error `Cannot find module '...' or its corresponding type declarations.`. Only `'./Layout'` works.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I see. I don't know much about tsconfig, but reading the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files) can you try including the `"files"`?

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
<Layout></Layout>
```

with

```
<Layout />
```

Comment: Can you explain why the latter works and the former doesn't?

Comment: in fact it doesn't, already tried it out.